# Enforce user & document specific tabs/fields within DocuSign embedded Sender screen

Tags: docusignapi

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that's using the DocuSign REST API to create a draft envelope, then redirect to the DocuSign Sender view, for the user to then manually add the relevant tabs/fields for each recipient, to each document.

Is there any way when creating the envelope, to state that for a given recipient, at least one signature field needs to be added (within the sender view) to a given document; for another recipient, they must add both a signature and initials field/tab to a given document, and so on. The result being that unless those criteria are met within the sender view, i.e. the sender has not added those necessary tabs/fields, then the sender cannot send the envelope until they've been added?

Basically, we don't know where on any documents these tabs/fields need to be applied, so we leave it up to the sender to add them in the DocuSign sender view, but it would be nice if we can ensure the sender does actually add the necessary tabs/fields accordingly - preventing the envelope from being sent with documents that have missing fields.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but it is tricky. Here's another way to look at solving the use case; what I think you're asking for:

1. Your application creates the envelope in draft format
2. Your application opens a sender view for the human to do their tagging of the document(s) for the recipient(s)
3. You want your application to now have the ability to check that the human did add a certain number of tabs for various recipients. If they did, then the envelope should continue on its way to the first recipient. Else, you want to have the human try again with the sender view, or abort the send, or make the alarms go off, etc.

Here's how you can do the above:

1. When your app creates the envelope in draft form, add an additional signer recipient, as an embedded signer. Something like

   {email: "noone@example.com", name: "App check tabs step", clientUserId: "1", routingOrder: "1"}
2. All the *real* recipients will also need their `routingOrder` to be set, and to a number above 1.
3. After the human completes the sender view (where they hopefully added the tags correctly), the envelope will be set to `sent` status and it will start to be routed. But since the first recipient is the embedded signer, the envelope will wait for your application to handle that recipient (because it is an embedded recipient).
4. After the human completes the sender view, your application can then "check" the envelope to see if the tabs were added per your specification--your app will just need to get the envelope recipients/tabs and check to see if the tabs were created.
5. Next step if the tabs were added correctly: your application should obtain an [EnvelopeLock](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks), then delete the embedded recipient, then delete the EnvelopeLock. Once you do this, the envelope routing will resume with the next recipient, the first "real" recipient.
6. If the the tabs were NOT added correctly, then you can probably open an Editing View screen for the human to fix the tabs. Or you could void the envelope. (Then re-check the envelope's tabs and then remove the embedded signer when you're ready for the envelope to proceed.)

The above works fine. There is a downside that the certificate of completion will show that the envelope was "corrected" when the "application user" was deleted.